# Why does this program output 8589934593 instead of 4294967298?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

This is a sample of abusing `void*` ptr (which is a bad coding practice itself), but it gets interesting when I look into memory details.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  long a;

  void print() {
    std::cout << a;
  }
} st;

int main() {
    int t[2] = {1,2};
    void* p = t;
    st* spt = (st*) p;
    spt->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Since `long` is 64-bit, and `int` is 32-bit, the two integers in t, `{1,2}` makes up the space for the `long a` in the `struct`.

But my question is, since now `{1,2}` makes up `a`, the binary memory alignment should be `00000000000000000000000000000001 00000000000000000000000000000010`, which should give `4294967298` in its decimal format. However, the actual printout is `8589934593`, which is `00000000000000000000000000000010 00000000000000000000000000000001`. It seems that the position of `1` and `2` are actually swapped.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think `00000000000000000000000000000001 00000000000000000000000000000010` is actually 4294967298

Comment: Maybe because your machine uses little endian.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: why long 64 bit? It depends on compiler, for Visual Studio compiler this is 4 bytes

Comment: Most architectures nowadays are little endian. And `long` is not always 64 bits. More importantly, `t` might not be aligned properly as a long and you'll got undefined behavior/crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a little-endian machine your `{ 1, 2 }` array is laid out in memory as the following sequence of bytes

```
01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00   // addresses increase from left to right
```

When re-interpreted as a 64-bit little-endian value, it produces `8589934593`.

On a big-endian machine the same array is laid out as

```
00 00 00 01  00 00 00 02   // addresses increase from left to right
```

When re-interpreted as a 64-bit big-endian value, it produces `4294967298`.

So, your experiment simply shows that you are running your code on a little-endian machine. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact. Numerically the answer can be simplified as an exponent of

```
2^n + 1: n=33
```

Which is

```
2^(33)+1 = 8589934593
```

and in binary is expressed as

```
1000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Lovely binary; has 32 zeroes, which in this case is n-1.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code in more portable way, it require c++11:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    union {
        uint32_t t[2];
        uint64_t a;
    } val;
    val.t[0] = 1;
    val.t[1] = 2;
    std::cout << val.a << ", " << std::hex << val.a << '\n';
}
```

The output on my amd64 machine is:

> 8589934593, 200000001

and it seems to completely valid, equal to `uint64_t(2) << 32 | uint64_t(1)`